# Bootstrap form-group. Three elements in one line

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `div`, where I have a `form-group`. 
 It is a `label` and beside a `TextAreaFor`. I need to display a text beside the `TextArea`, but the text it's always under the `TextArea`, as you can see here.
[image]

```
 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Remarks, new { @class = "control-label col-md-offset-1 col-md-3" })
       <div class="col-md-8">
          @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Remarks, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
          <label for="textbox1" class="form-inline" > I need text here</label>
        </div>                   
      </div>
```

I've tried with `form-inline`
I've tried to add `class= "col-md-2"` for the label, but none of these resolved my problem. 
can you advise, please?

Comment: Try to put both of them in a `<div class"row">` then close the `</div>`. Your `form-group` is in a container class ?

Comment: It is in a '<div class="col-lg-6">' which it is iin a  '<fieldset class="form-horizontal">'

Comment: It's Bootstrap 3 or 4 ?

Comment: It's 3. the form-inline doesn't resloved this problem

Comment: Like @core114 show you, it's not necessary to use asp.net to create a Label or a TextArea when you use Bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Bobs</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    I need text here
    </div>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

or try this **form-inline**
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: The documentation link is that of bootstrap version 4 and it uses the 3rd version. Better to use this link : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Comment: @FoxCy sir, this one is better for him https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline_sr&stacked=h